# I can't retrieve large files from AWS Bucket using java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, primefaces, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a Bucket in the **Region:    Oregon**, I'm using the **aws java sdk**, with small files I don't have problems but when I try to download a file of 40 MB I get a **Network error** in the browser.

I'm using Java, Primefaces and **role based authentication**.

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
AmazonS3 s3= new AmazonS3Client(clientConfig);
s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

Method to get the file :

```
public StreamedContent getFile() {
        S3Object obj = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(ProjectConstants.BUCKET_NAME,
                ProjectConstants.OBJECT_NAME));
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(obj.getObjectContent(), "application/octet-stream", "file.exe");
    }
```

Facelet code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="#{viewDow.button_download}" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);">
<p:fileDownload value="#{downloadController.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Note: I don't get exceptions.

I get the next error :

[image]

Comment: Can you download files around that size from other sources? So that it's definitely not a network limitation?

Comment: I can download the same file using the amazon s3 console

Comment: no log from your server ? there's cupple of settings on timeout (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html)) that you could play with if we knew more. also can prime faces `DefaultStreamedContent` handle large files (just to eliminate its not an issue from there)